# What does TeamExplorerTracksActiveItem do?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I've stumbeld upon this registry key but haven't found any documentation what it does.

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Behavior\TeamExplorerTracksActiveItem

Does anyone knows?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/03/29/track-active-item-in-solution-explorer-vstipproj0011.aspx

Comment: @Mat changing this in the UI doesn't change the value in the registry, though it seems the underlying value for it

Comment: Seeing at your path I guess you have Microsoft's [Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2010 (TFS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff637362) installed. Its a product that MS endorses for Agile Development & tracking of the development processes. Even if you dont install it manually some of its dependencies are found in VS2010 folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This setting determines whether the team project selection in Team Explorer should track the currently active item (provided that item has a mapped local path and a bound solution/project is open).

Comment: Making it only really useful when you are connected to multiple team projects on the same server and project collection